# CROS error on magento2 while using external API

Tags: magento2, api

I am trying to access an api using jquery in magento2

Here is my jquery code

```
<script>
require(['jquery'],function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".result").hide();
        jQuery("#form_value").submit(function(){
            
         

            var url = "https://url.com";
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
           
            showLoader: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response.output);
                jQuery(".result").show();
                jQuery(".result").text(response.output);
            }
        });
        return false;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

But i am getting error as CROS policy error .. i have added following code in .htacess but still getting same error

```
SetEnvIf Accept application/json API
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=API
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT" env=API
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization" env=API
```

anything that i am missing?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: what webserver are you using? on magento2 side

Comment: I am using Apache Server.